# No puedo usar "pip" en la consola

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Estoy comenzando y quiero crear un ejecutable de Python a través de pip, pero al colocarlo en la consola me dice

> "pip" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Al buscar en internet instalé un pip que encontré y el resultado fue el siguiente:[image: Instalacion de pip]

Pero aún me sale el mismo problema al tratar de utilizar pip.
No sé cuál pueda ser el problema.

Comment: Hola, puede indicar la versión exacta de Python que tienes instalado?

Comment: `python -m pip` te permite usarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es porque no agregaste la variable de entorno. Tiene dos formas de solucionarlo.

1- Puedes reinstalar python, en el asistente debes tildar la **opción:**

> **"add python to environment variables".**

2- la otra forma sería agregando manualmente las variables de entorno, para esto creas una nueva variable de entorno con el nombre "Path" y agregas lo siguiente como valor:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Python\Pythonxx-xx\
C:\Python\Pythonxx-xx\Scripts\
```

Donde `xx-xx` depende la versión que tengas instalda.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el mensaje de error, por algún motivo no se agregaron los binarios de pip a la variable de ambiente PATH, la cual permite acceder a aplicaciones de consola por medio de su nombre directamente como quieres.

Tal y como dice el mensaje de error, la solución consiste en agregar la ruta que aparece ahí, que es donde está instalando PIP a esta variable de ambiente.

A continuación te explico como agregarla:

1. Presiona la tecla Windows + R para ejecutar el editor de variables de ambiente.
2. Escribe en el campo `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` y dale Aceptar.
3. En recuadro de arriba (Variables de ambientes para `<tu_usuario>`), busca la variable con nombre `path`, presionala y aprieta editar.
4. En la ventana presiona agregar y pega la ruta que contiene los binarios.
5. Dale aceptar y reinicia el terminal.
6. Ahora podrás acceder solo escribiendo pip.

La ruta que posee los binarios de pip es la que aparece en la imagen que incluiste. Como es una imagen no puedo hacer copy paste pero tú sí podrás obtenerla y así, agregarla a las variables de ambiente.